# Unbind a Clojure var

Tags: clojure, var

Let's say I have a dynamic var that starts off unbound:

```
(def ^:dynamic *config-param*)
```

Then, later, it is set like this:

```
(alter-var-root #'*config-param* (constantly 42)))
```

But, now, I want to unbind it (perhaps for testing purposes). How do I do it?

(Note: I am *not* endorsing the use of dynamic variables! I'm just asking.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.unbindRoot` like this:

```
(.unbindRoot #'*config-param*)
```